# Is there any way to add another tag with all the details at specific place in java without using any parser

Tags: java, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      N
      <price>5.95</price>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk103">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
      <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
      society in England, the young survivors lay the 
      foundation for a new society.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk104">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Oberon's Legacy</title>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2001-03-10</publish_date>
      <description>In post-apocalypse England, the mysterious 
      agent known only as Oberon helps to create a new life 
      for the inhabitants of London. Sequel to Maeve 
      Ascendant.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk105">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>The Sundered Grail</title>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2001-09-10</publish_date>
      <description>The two daughters of Maeve, half-sisters, 
      battle one another for control of England. Sequel to 
      Oberon's Legacy.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk106">
      <author>Randall, Cynthia</author>
      <title>Lover Birds</title>
      <genre>Romance</genre>
      <price>4.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-09-02</publish_date>
      <description>When Carla meets Paul at an ornithology 
      conference, tempers fly as feathers get ruffled.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk107">
      <author>Thurman, Paula</author>
      <title>Splish Splash</title>
      <genre>Romance</genre>
      <price>4.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date>
      <description>A deep sea diver finds true love twenty 
      thousand leagues beneath the sea.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk108">
      <author>Knorr, Stefan</author>
      <title>Creepy Crawlies</title>
      <genre>Horror</genre>
      <price>4.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-06</publish_date>
      <description>An anthology of horror stories about roaches,
      centipedes, scorpions  and other insects.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk109">
      <author>Kress, Peter</author>
      <title>Paradox Lost</title>
      <genre>Science Fiction</genre>
      <price>6.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date>
      <description>After an inadvertant trip through a Heisenberg
      Uncertainty Device, James Salway discovers the problems 
      of being quantum.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk110">
      <author>O'Brien, Tim</author>
      <title>Microsoft .NET: The Programming Bible</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>36.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-09</publish_date>
      <description>Microsoft's .NET initiative is explored in 
      detail in this deep programmer's reference.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk111">
      <author>O'Brien, Tim</author>
      <title>MSXML3: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>36.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-01</publish_date>
      <description>The Microsoft MSXML3 parser is covered in 
      detail, with attention to XML DOM interfaces, XSLT processing, 
      SAX and more.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk112">
      <author>Galos, Mike</author>
      <title>Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>49.95</price>
      <publish_date>2001-04-16</publish_date>
      <description>Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth,
      looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ are 
      integrated into a comprehensive development 
      environment.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

Suppose if i want to add another tag i.e book id=111,with all the details,logic i was trying to apply is to read the xml as string  and count the number of characters.After this i will read the xml till where i want to replace and then iterate over entire xm(string) if i encountered the specific index then i will add.Is there any better way to achieve this without using parser.Thanks in advance

Comment: Any specific reason to not use parser?

Comment: I don't  have much knowledge or enough exposure to use parser

Answer (score 1):

Does this have to be in Java? It's much easier to do this in XSLT (which you can invoke from Java). For example if you supply the extra book as the value of parameter $newbook (as a string containing lexical XML), then adding it to the document is simply

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">
  <xsl:param name="newbook"/>
  <xsl:template match="/catalog">
    <catalog>
      <xsl:copy-of select="*, parse-xml($newbook)"/>
    </catalog>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

This uses XSLT 3.0 (e.g. Saxon) but an XSLT 1.0 solution (using the built-in JDK XSLT processor) is quite possible too, just a bit more wordy.

An XSLT solution will, of course, use a real XML parser beneath the hood. You definitely don't want to be processing XML without using a real parser, we see hundreds of questions on StackOverflow from people who have got themselves into a mess by doing that.

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like this. This is not the ideal way, Since you are not using any XML parsers, just append the new XML at the required position.

Also note that this is not a general answer, This answer is very specific to this problem and its requirements.

```
String xml = // your current XML String

StringBuilder originalXML = new StringBuilder( xml );

// Assume you want to inser after bk112
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( "(<book id=\"bk112\">)([\\s\\S]*?)(<\\/book>)" );
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( xml );
boolean isMatch = matcher.find();

if ( isMatch )
{
  String group1 = matcher.group();

  // new book tag you want to insert
  String newBook ="<book id=\"bk113\">\n" +
                            "      <author>Test Author</author>\n" +
                            "      <title>Test Title</title>\n" +
                            "      <genre>Test</genre>\n" +
                            "      <price>49.95</price>\n" +
                            "      <publish_date>2001-04-16</publish_date>\n" +
                            "      <description>Lorem Ipsum...</description>\n" +
                            "   </book>\n";

  // get the last index of required tag. i.e. bk112
  originalXML.insert( originalXML.lastIndexOf( "<book id=\"bk112\">" ) + group1.length(), newBook );
  System.out.println(originalXML.toString());
} 
else 
{ 
  System.out.println( "failed to match regex" ); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks,but this is appending at end,if i want to add in between is this possible?

Comment: @Anil I have updated my answer, please check if it helps and let me know

Comment: Please don't advise anyone to process XML without using a real XML parser. We have to deal with hundreds of questions from people dealing with ill-formed XML that only exists because of someone taking that kind of short-cut. This solution is going to fail if the attribute is in single quotes, if there's extra whitespace in the tag, if there are comments or CDATA sections, etc etc.

Comment: Problem specifically say not to use a parser and in my answer i have already said that this is not the ideal way. This is a way that suits the requirement. And the problem specifically say the element will not change when adding